# Decryption of file missing ~10 characters from ending

Tags: c#, cryptography, encryption

I've written Encryption/Decryption methods using the `RC2CryptoServiceProvider` in C# and for some reason, I cannot get my decryptor to decrypt the final few bytes.  The file seems to just cut off.  My encryption method looks like:

```
    public static byte[] EncryptString(byte[] input, string password)
    {
        PasswordDeriveBytes pderiver = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, null);
        byte[] ivZeros = new byte[8];
        byte[] pbeKey = pderiver.CryptDeriveKey("RC2", "MD5", 128, ivZeros);

        RC2CryptoServiceProvider RC2 = new RC2CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] IV = new byte[8];
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = RC2.CreateEncryptor(pbeKey, IV);

        MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        csEncrypt.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
        csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();

        return msEncrypt.ToArray();
    }
```

While my decryption looks like:

```
    public static byte[] DecryptString(byte[] input, string password, int originalSize)
    {
        PasswordDeriveBytes pderiver = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, null);
        byte[] ivZeros = new byte[8];
        byte[] pbeKey = pderiver.CryptDeriveKey("RC2", "MD5", 128, ivZeros);

        RC2CryptoServiceProvider RC2 = new RC2CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] IV = new byte[8];
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = RC2.CreateDecryptor(pbeKey, IV);

        MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        csDecrypt.Write(input, 0, originalSize);
       // csDecrypt.FlushFinalBlock();

        char[] decrypted = new char[input.Length];
        decrypted = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(msDecrypt.ToArray());
        return msDecrypt.ToArray();

    }
```

The char[] `decrypted` is returning the whole file decrypted, except the file ends with `</LudoData>` and when decrypting, I only get up to the first `<` character.

I have been playing with the lengths of things and nothing is changing anything.  In my specific case, `input` is of length 11296, and `originalSize` is of size 11290.  However, `decrypted` ends up being of size *11280* when decrypting.  What gives!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there a reason that you have the Flush() commented out? Have you tried fully closing your streams?

Comment: He's writing to both crypto streams which means he has to flush the final block in both, that's definitely for sure.

Comment: I had it commented out because of a runtime error I was recieving that I fixed, then forgot about the Flush.  This somehow solved everything.  I don't understand at all, but thanks!

Comment: SO, yes, the wretched flush issue rears his head again.  I've encountered this many time before.  In fact, I've had it working on my dev server thinking everything is OK, and then BAM! it rears its head in a production enviornment--even with the same exact data!  Crazy, huh?  It was all due to forgetting to flush.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, I fought this battle about a month ago and had a very similar issue, except I was experiencing TOO much on the end.  ToArray was my solution.

You're doing some weird stuff here I'm not exactly sure of.  You're using cryptostreams when you don't have to, you're keeping track of the original length for some weird reason and you're using deprecated classes.  Your issue is probably a combination of padding, incorrect assumptions (evidenced by originalLength) and incorrect handling of streams (which can be tricky).  Try this instead:

Encrypt:

```
var rij = RijndaelManaged.Create();
rij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
rij.BlockSize = 256;
rij.KeySize = 256;
rij.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126;
var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 
          Encoding.Default.GetBytes("lolwtfbbqsalt" + password));
var enc = rij.CreateEncryptor(pdb.GetBytes(rij.KeySize / 8), 
          pdb.GetBytes(rij.BlockSize / 8));
return enc.TransformFinalBlock(unencryptedBytes, 0, unencryptedBytes.Length);
```

Decrypt:

```
// throws a cryptographic exception if password is wrong
var rij = RijndaelManaged.Create();
rij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
rij.BlockSize = 256;
rij.KeySize = 256;
rij.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126;
var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 
          Encoding.Default.GetBytes("lolwtfbbqsalt" + password));
var dec = rij.CreateDecryptor(pdb.GetBytes(rij.KeySize / 8), 
          pdb.GetBytes(rij.BlockSize / 8));
return dec.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, 
          encryptedBytes.Length);
```

Notice the only thing different within these two methods are CreateEncryptor/CreateDecryptor, so you can refactor out lots of duplication.  Also notice I get in a byte array and get out a byte array without having to use any streams.  Its also a bit more secure than RC2, and would be even more so if the salt were more random.

Comment: I am using RC2 because this also has to be compatible with a C++ application that takes in an RC2 encrypted file

Answer (score 0):

RC2.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

both in encryption and decryption is what probably is missing.